# How do Splat Zones (Ranked Mode) work?

Tags: splatoon, splatoon-2

Do we take possession of the Splat Zone when we've covered over 50% of the zone? Do we need an inkling within the perimeter to take it?

How does it work?

Comment: It looks like it only needs to be contained by ink. See [here](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Splat_Zones).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After having played a few matches:

It seems as though you need the majority (75%+) of the Splat Zone. You definitely do not need anyone in it; I took many from overhead. Taking a Splat Zone means that the whole thing will briefly turn to your ink color, entirely (so if it was, say, 95% your ink, it will now be 100%).

If the zone is currently controlled by the opposing team, when your team covers around 50% of the zone, it will become neutral again so that if either team reaches around 75% coverage, it will fully change (back) to that team's color.

If the control switches from one team to the other, the previous holding team will have time added to their timer so they will have to hold the zone for a longer amount of time if they capture it again.  The amount of time added is greater if the current time remaining is low and if the zone was continually held for longer.  This extra time is separate from the main score and doesn't count when determining the winner.

All maps have either one or two splat zones. In maps with two zones, control of each zone is the same as usual, but the timer will only count down for a team when that team controls both zones.

Comment: Answers the question of whether or not we need an inkling inside, so I'll accept this. If more data comes along to support the 75%, please update

Comment: Will do. It's pretty hard to tell in the heat of battle but I don't think I'm far off.

Comment: It should be noted that in maps with two zones, control of each zone is the same as usual, but the timer will only tick down when a team controls both of them.

Comment: @Brian Feel free to edit information in if you think it would be beneficial.