# What are the rules for "Extra Time"?

Tags: splatoon

In my previous ranked battle of Splatoon the scores were quite close to each other. We were ahead and the time ran out, so we should have won. However, there was something about "Extra Time" on my screen, and we kept on playing. Was this because the scores were too close to each other? What are the rules for this, and when is the winner decided?

Comment: Do you mean Extra time like in this question: [How do Splat Zones work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/222008/51332)  Or as in Overtime? (When the 5 minute match timer has ended)

Comment: No, that is the double counter as shown in a previous [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222636/whats-up-with-this-double-counter-in-ranked-mode) of me. I am referring to extra playing time, not countdown time. So the overtime you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Splatoon Blog](http://splatoonus.tumblr.com/post/121124223787/and-now-for-some-nitty-gritty-ranked-battle):

> - If neither counter reaches zero by the time limit, The team with The lower counter wins.
> - **The match time will be extended if the losing team has the Splat Zones captured when time runs out.**
> - Don’t give up until it’s over!

And here's a [redditor's experience](http://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/38ed5h/why_does_splat_zones_go_into_overtime/crudc60) in battle:

> If the losing team currently dominates the splat zone, the game goes
>   into overtime to give them the last stretch chance to overtake the
>   opposing team.
>
> Let's say your team is losing with 60 : 30. Now your team has the
>   splat zone and time's up. It goes into overtime because you have the
>   splat zone and thus have a chance to still win. Now if you keep it
>   until 29, the game ends and you win. However, if the opposing team
>   takes back the splat zone, the game ends and they win.

From my experience, Splatoon's Splat Zone shares this same trait with TF2's King of the Hill mode.  The game will end after 5 minutes (match timer) if both of the following criteria are met:

1. Neither team managed to bring their own team counter down to 0
2. The dominate team (based on whoever has the least amount of time on their team counter) currently owns the splat zone, or the zone is neutralize (and not counting towards either team).

Because of this, It is possible to go into Overtime if the losing team takes control of the Splat Zone before the 5 minute match timer is up. As long as they hold the zone(s), their team counter will continue to count down, even after the match timer is over.  As soon as the losing team manages to get 1 second below their opponent's timer, then both of the previous match criteria will be met and the win will go to the *new* dominate team.

Comment: One more detail: If during overtime the Splat Zone goes neutral and stays neutral, that is no team has control, the game will wait for about 10 seconds and then end. The team with the lower counter will win. I don't know exactly how long this neutral grace period is, but in my experience it's around 10 seconds.

Comment: I've had Rainmaker go into overtime once, does anyone know if this works similarly? I've had lots of games when the losing team's held the rainmaker at game end and it _didn't_ go into overtime, could it be something to do with how close they are to retaking the lead?